# Github Action - Docker build: file not found in build context or excluded

Tags: docker, dockerfile, github-actions

I'm having issues with my Github action where I'm trying to build my Docker image after building my jar and it throws this error:

```
Step 8/9 : COPY /home/runner/work/js-sites-client-api/js-sites-client-api/build/libs/client-portal-api.jar app.jar
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat home/runner/work/js-sites-client-api/js-sites-client-api/build/libs/client-portal-api.jar: file does not exist
```

Which doesn't make sense to me because I ran LS/PWD and I can see that the file IS there:

```
  ls build/libs
  cd build/libs
  pwd
  cd ../../
  docker build . --file Dockerfile --tag ***/js-client-api:latest
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    JAVA_HOME: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk/11.0.14-1/x64
    GRADLE_BUILD_ACTION_CACHE_RESTORED: true
-------------OUTPUT of ls/pwd------------
client-portal-api.jar
/home/runner/work/js-sites-client-api/js-sites-client-api/build/libs
```

Below is my github action:

```
...

jobs:

  build:
...

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v2
      with:
        java-version: '11'
        distribution: 'temurin'
        server-id: github # Value of the distributionManagement/repository/id field of the pom.xml
        settings-path: ${{ github.workspace }} # location for the settings.xml file
    - name: Change wrapper permissions
      run: chmod +x ./gradlew
    - name: Build with Gradle
      uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@937999e9cc2425eddc7fd62d1053baf041147db7
      with:
        arguments: build
    
    - name: Log in to Docker Hub
      uses: docker/login-action@f054a8b539a109f9f41c372932f1ae047eff08c9
      with:
        username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
    
    - name: Build the Docker image
      run: |
        ls build/libs
        cd build/libs
        pwd
        cd ../../
        docker build . --file Dockerfile --tag ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}/js-client-api:latest --build-arg WORKDIR=${{ github.workspace }}
    
    - name: Push the Docker image
      run: docker push ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}/js-client-api:latest
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in your Dockerfile is the issue:
`COPY /home/runner/work/js-sites-client-api/js-sites-client-api/build/libs/client-portal-api.jar app.jar`. In a Dockerfile `COPY`, the first argument is the location of the file(s) on the machine, which has to be a relative path, not an absolute one. Read more [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)

> Multiple  resources may be specified but the paths of files and directories will be interpreted as relative to the source of the context of the build.

Comment: thank you! Didn't know you couldn't use absolute paths. build/libs/*.jar solved the issue